# Using separate in tidyr to separate column after a certain number of characters?

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

Sample of data:

```
  Outcome            
  <chr>              
1 X2016-17Denominator
2 X2014-15Denominator
3 X2014-15Outcome    
4 X2010-11Numerator  
5 X2012-13Denominator
```

I'm a bit uncertain how to use the `sep` argument in the `separate` function provided by the `tidyr` package. I'm still a newbie at using regex but I figured something like this would work:

```
sample %<>% separate(Outcome, into=c("date", "metric"), sep="^X[:digit:]{4}[:punct:][:digit:]{2}")
```

This creates the `metric` column fine, but leaves the date column empty. I'm guessing the issue is that what is considered the "separator" isn't replicated, but I'm not sure how to specify the characters after `X####-##` as what I want the columns to be separated by.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate by position.

```
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  separate(Outcome, into=c("date", "metric"), sep = 8)
#       date      metric
# 1 X2016-17 Denominator
# 2 X2014-15 Denominator
# 3 X2014-15     Outcome
# 4 X2010-11   Numerator
# 5 X2012-13 Denominator
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "  Outcome            
1 'X2016-17Denominator'
2 'X2014-15Denominator'
3 'X2014-15Outcome'    
4 'X2010-11Numerator'  
5 'X2012-13Denominator'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`separate` is used to separate column given a separator (so you are using your regex as a separator, hence it's only keeping `metric`, as it thinks the rest is what should separate your columns). In this case you should use `extract`

```
sample = data.frame(Outcome = c(
    'X2016-17Denominator', 
    'X2014-15Denominator',
    'X2014-15Outcome',
    'X2010-11Numerator',
    'X2012-13Denominator'
))

sample %>% 
    extract(
        Outcome, 
        into=c("date", "metric"),
        regex="^X([:digit:]{4}[:punct:][:digit:]{2})(.*)"
    )
#    date      metric
#1 2016-17 Denominator
#2 2014-15 Denominator
#3 2014-15     Outcome
#4 2010-11   Numerator
#5 2012-13 Denominator
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also a regex lookaround to `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Outcome = str_remove(Outcome, "^X")) %>% 
    separate(Outcome, into = c("date", "metric"), sep="(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])")
#     date      metric
#1 2016-17 Denominator
#2 2014-15 Denominator
#3 2014-15     Outcome
#4 2010-11   Numerator
#5 2012-13 Denominator
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Outcome = c("X2016-17Denominator", "X2014-15Denominator", 
 "X2014-15Outcome", "X2010-11Numerator", "X2012-13Denominator"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
 ))
```